# How to fix potential Memory leak when using node and nightwatch for loop?

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I am attempting to for-loop over an array of elements in a website and the for-loop works just fine, except for this error I get MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

I have tried to add the events module and use the event emitter.setMaxListeners() method and I still get this error. I even put it in the for-loop to stay ahead of all other even listeners. I've console.logged my number of max listeners and can't figure out why I'm still getting this.

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {

        //console.log(emmiter)
        browser
            .element('css selector', `mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i})`, 
function(result) {
                if(result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
                    browser.isVisible(`mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i})`, 
function(result) {
                        if(result.value === true) {

emmiter.setMaxListeners(emmiter.getMaxListeners() + 1)
                            console.log(emmiter);
                            browser.click(`mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i})`)
                            .pause(2000)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            //.pause(2000)

            //.pause(10000)

    }
```

When I loop over multiple elements I would expect them to loop through without error. In this case I would loop over without having a memory leak warning. Currently, I get the warning when going inside this for loop and it seems to be occurring in one of my if statements.

Comment: Hey Jack! Can you add the `package.json` *dependencies & devDependencies*? I haven't seen this error yet and I looped through hundreds of elements at a time. What Nightwatch@vx.y.z?

Comment: Here is my package.json

Comment: {
  "name": "galaxy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "nightwatch.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": ""
  },
  "author": "jgunther",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "nightwatch": "^1.0.18"
  }
}

Comment: I recently rolled back to nightwatch version 0.9.21 and I didn't get the memory leak error. My guess this is new in this version of nightwatch but it's annoying to see those errors.

Comment: Glad you worked it out @Jack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a new console output feature for the latest release of Nightwatch.

I encountered the issue on 1.0.18.

I recently rolled back to nightwatch version 0.9.21 and I didn't get the memory leak error. My guess this is new in this version of nightwatch but it's annoying to see those errors.